# after upgrading module, errors for missing fonts referenced in project.pbxproj file

Tags: xcode, react-native, native-base

I'm in the process of upgrading my react native project to the latest react native version, as well as the modules. One module that seems to be causing me problems is upgrading Native Base v2.x to v3.4.

During the ios build I'm getting errors for missing Font files in the node_modules/native-base/Fonts directory.  It looks like this is from referenced files in the ios project.pbxproj file.

Here is one such error:
{PROJECT_ROOT}/node_modules/native-base/Fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf error build: {PROJECT_ROOT}/node_modules/native-base/Fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf: No such file or directory

I haven't been able to figure out how to cleanly rebuild the project.pbxproj file, so that it no longer has references to files that are not used or available.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around my issue by manually removing any references to the missing Font files in the project.pbxproj file. This, however doesn't seem like the proper way to avoid this issue. Hoping someone else has some insight to resolving this problem another way. Thanks,